# Random password variable disappears

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm using the following to generate a random password in a shell script:

```
DBPASS=</dev/urandom tr -dc A-Za-z0-9| (head -c $1 > /dev/null 2>&1 || head -c 8)
```

When i run this in a file on its own like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
DBPASS=</dev/urandom tr -dc A-Za-z0-9| (head -c $1 > /dev/null 2>&1 || head -c 8)
echo $DBPASS
```

A password is echoed. When i incorporate it into a larger script though the variable never seems to get created for some reason,

so for example this doesn't work (the oldpass string is replaced with nothing):

```
DBPASS=</dev/urandom tr -dc A-Za-z0-9| (head -c $1 > /dev/null 2>&1 || head -c 8)
sed -i s/oldpass/$DBPASS/ mysql_connect.php
```

If i manually set the variable though everything is fine. I must admit i'm not totally sure how the password is being generated. If it helps to clarify what the issue might be, this script is contained within a postwwwact cPanel script

can anyone see what the issue might be?

Comment: You might want to just look at something like [apg](http://www.adel.nursat.kz/apg/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `$1` evaluates to null (unset), the second `head` is run and it's what's outputting the string. The `echo` is not since `$DBPASS` is null. You need to use command substitution to get the output into the variable:

```
DBPASS=$(</dev/urandom tr -dc A-Za-z0-9| (head -c $1 > /dev/null 2>&1 || head -c 8))
```

Also, since the first `head` is redirected to `/dev/null`, nothing will be output if `$1` is not null. What is it that you inted for that clause to do?

If what you're wanting is to provide a default length if one is not provided as an argument, then try this:

```
DBPASS=$(</dev/urandom tr -dc '[:alnum:]' | head -c ${1:-8} 2>&1)
```

I threw in the `'[:alnum:]'` for free.

Comment: to be honest this is just a snippet i was given by another developer, can it be improved?

Comment: Thanks, fyi i basically want an 8 character random password, there will never be an argument passed to it.

Comment: so i guess that makes it: $(</dev/urandom tr -dc '[:alnum:]' | head -c 8 2>&1)